# Change the master of a branch in GIT

Tags: git, github, branch, rebase, git-rebase

I have a Master branch, lets say A.
I branched B from A.
I started working on B, for a new release, but after a while I found a issue in A, that I needed to change now.
I changed that in A, but I want to change it on B also. How can I do that?
I tried with git rebase, but it just screwed up my B branch.
I tried with gitmerge, but it just deletes all the changed that I made to the B branch
Merging I tried it like this, from the B branch:

```
git merge master (where master = A)
```

with rebase I tried:

```
git rebase master
```

Got some conflicts, resolved them, but then I had a lot of missing files from the B branch

EDIT: I retried and now I got at a error that says:

passenger/src/main/java/nl/hgrams/passenger/utils/ProfileData.java: needs merge
passenger/src/main/res/layout/list_profile_data.xml: needs merge

Now I tried to merge, but when opening the files with mate, or git merge tool, the files are empty. Now the files did not exist in branch A, but should exist on B

EDIT2:
Went past that, resolved it somehow, git --rebase continue finished, and I had issues in all my project, on that branch. Resolved them but still have problems because of resources:

Error:(26, 32) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'textColor' with value '@color/green4D').
Error:(31, 27) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/timeline2').
Error:(64, 40) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'textColor' with value '@color/green4D').
Error:(86, 35) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/kilometers2').
Error:(91, 40) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'textColor' with value '@color/green4D').
Error:(136, 40) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'textColor' with value '@color/green4D').
Error:(141, 35) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/travel_mode').
Error:(183, 40) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'textColor' with value '@color/green4D').
Error:(188, 35) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/leaderboard').
Error:(203, 38) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/circle').

Comment: Did you continue your rebase after you resolved the conflicts? Git is pretty explicit about this, you have to run `git rebase --continue` after any conflicts occured.

Comment: yes of course, when I tried to rebase, and I resolved my conflict, but still, I had files missing. Whats even more stranger is that I had a conflict in a file in which I worked on B branch, but after branching B from A, I didn't worked on that file in branch A.

Comment: Well, `git rebase` is the command you are looking for, you seem to know this. The only thing you tell us "something went wrong rebasing", we can't offer you any help on this basis, so you'll have to update your question with details if you still want an answer.

Comment: enough details? it seems really weird, cause it didn't asked me on resolving conflicts in the Android Manifest file, or other files that I modified on both branches, but asks to resolv conflicts on files that I only modified on branch B (changes I NEED)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved all of the conflicts, after a while, and even thought some files really where empty after, I took them from my B branch, and then looked over them and the A branch files in order to make the needed modifications to it. After I did that, I pushed it on the server and resolved this issue.